# Does AppHarbor support Microsoft Katana?

Tags: appharbor, owin, katana

I suspect I can guess the answer to this, but since I couldn't find anything in the FAQ or on StackOverflow I might as well ask. Can I use Microsoft's implementation of [OWIN](http://owin.org/), [Katana](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/documentation), on AppHarbor?

As an aside, I suppose I should also check my understanding: Does this question make sense? AppHarbor appears to deploy web projects to IIS. Since OWIN is an *alternative* to IIS, is this even within the scope of AppHarbor's business model?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb) to run OWIN/Katana apps on top of IIS - that should work on the default AppHarbor IIS setup. More info:

- http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-middleware-in-the-iis-integrated-pipeline
- http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll try this and if I can get it to work as described, I'll mark it as the answer. It occurs to me that this hosting model might have been designed specifically for this kind of host, as one of Microsoft's stated goals with Katana was to eliminate dependency on System.Web. This doesn't do that, but it does fulfil the aim of running OWIN apps in IIS.

Comment: Any luck with this? I can't get my OWIN test app to run